# draw(_ rect: CGRect) in custom UITextField class don't call on ios 14

Tags: swift, uitextfield, ios14

I use draw(_ rect: CGRect) in custom UITextField class.
Draw function works on IOS 13 but it doesn't work on IOS 14.
I added setNeedsDisplay() in init but still doesn't work after using the setNeedsDisplay()

```
func setup() {
    let border = CALayer()
    let width = CGFloat(2.0)
    border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - width, width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
    border.borderWidth = width
    self.layer.addSublayer(border)
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setNeedsDisplay()
    
}

required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setNeedsDisplay()
}

public override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    setup()
    self.backgroundColor = .red
}
```

Comment: using draw function while you are not drawing anything is not a good approach... is there any specific reason you want to use draw function ?

Comment: I had reported this issue to apple. Didn’t get the response yet. Will update once I get it

Comment: It is fixed i guess in iOS 14 beta5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your draw function to didMoveToWindows

Always ask me :)

```
override func didMoveToWindow() {
     self.layer.addSublayer(border)
     self.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

Comment: This is not the proper method to add custom drawings

Comment: @InderKumarRathore can you suggest good way for this issue in ios 14 ?

Answer (score 0):

You should not add anything in layoutSubviews or in Draw function

```
 private lazy var border : CALayer = {
    let layer = CALayer()
    layer.borderWidth = CGFloat(2.0)
    return layer
}()


 override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
  private func commonInit(){
             setup() 
            self.backgroundColor = .red
        }


  public override func layoutSubviews() {
        
         border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - width, width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
         
      }

  private  func setup() {
       self.layer.addSublayer(border)
       self.layer.masksToBounds = true

      }
```